# How to dispatch an action containing catch error and display to the user via component

Tags: angular, ngrx, effects

I am having an angular 8 application, where a component dispatch an action, the effect will catch the action and calls the service then it will throw an error in the catch. But in the console i am able to get the exact error received from spring rest api. But i am not getting the error in the component which i am trying to use store.select gives me `error: null`. In the reducer, i am having a case for error and return back the error as error: `action.payload`.

For brief understanding i am placing my code below

> component.ts

When submitting the form i am dispatching an authenticate action and using `store.select`

```
submitForm() {
        this.store.dispatch(new Login(this.loginForm.value));
        this.store.select('auth').subscribe(state =>  console.log(state));=
    }
```

> action.ts

```
export enum AuthActionTypes {
  LOGIN = '[Auth] Login',
  LOGIN_SUCCESS = '[Auth] Login Success',
  AUTHENTICATED = '[Auth] Authenticated',
  FAILURE = '[Auth] Failure'
}

export class Login implements Action {
  readonly type = AuthActionTypes.LOGIN;

  constructor(public payload: any) {
  }
}

export class Authenticated implements Action {
  readonly type = AuthActionTypes.AUTHENTICATED;

  constructor(public payload: any | null) {
  }
}

export class LoginSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS;

  constructor(public payload: any) {
  }
}

export class Failure implements Action {
  readonly type = AuthActionTypes.FAILURE;

  constructor(public payload: any) {
  }
}

export type AuthActions =
  Login
  | Authenticated
  | LoginSuccess
  | Failure;
```

> effect.ts

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false})
  login$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType(AuthActionTypes.LOGIN),
      map((action: Login) => action.payload),
      switchMap(credentials => 
        this.authService.logIn(credentials)
          .pipe(
            map((data) => {
              this.router.navigate(['/']);
            }              
            ),
            tap(() => {}
            ),
            catchError((error) => {
              return of(
                new Failure(error));
            })
          )
      ),
    );
```

> reducer.ts

```
export interface State {
    authenticated: boolean;
    username: User | null;
    token: string | null;
    error: any;
}

export const initialState: State = {
  authenticated: false,
  username: null,
  token: undefined,
  error: null
};

export function reducer(state: State = initialState, action: AuthActions): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, authenticated: true, error: null}
    case AuthActionTypes.FAILURE:
        let authErrorPush = state.error;
      console.log(authErrorPush);
        return { ...state, authenticated: false , error: action.payload}
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

export const getError = (state: State) => state.error;
```

Can anyone help me to get the error from the catch and display to the user via component which i have `this.store.select('auth')`. Or any suggestions or reference, or any wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not dispatching an action back to the store via the effect.
This is due to `dispatch: false`.

Change:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
```

To

```
@Effect()
```

So the effect will dispatch the actions back to the store

Comment: Please mark this as your answer to close the question. Thanks!